# Spring Cloud for AWS - how to convert a message received from SQS and sent by S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, spring-cloud

I have configured S3 to fire an event every time a file is uploaded. The event goes to SQS. Now I want to read messages from the queue with Spring Cloud for AWS. Is there a way to convert the payload to a known type which represents S3 Event record? I've tried with

```
package com.test;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Headers;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;

import com.amazonaws.services.s3.event.S3EventNotification.S3EventNotificationRecord;

public class SQSHandler {
    @MessageMapping("MediaQueue")
    private void receiveMessage(S3EventNotificationRecord message, @Headers Map<String, String> headers) {
        System.out.println("MYK MYK MYK");
    }
}
```

but I get error

> ord, message=GenericMessage [payload={here was whole payload}]
>       at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PayloadArgumentResolver.java:115)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:447)
>       ... 8 more

Do you know any method to do something like this?

Comment: Do you found answer for this? Have you solved the problem

Comment: Yes. You have to take String parameter and then parse it to an object with Amazon SDK. Please take a look at an answer which I will post in a second.

Answer (score 5):

The solution to the problem is following:

```
 import com.amazonaws.services.s3.event.S3EventNotification;

 @MessageMapping("${mediaQueueName}")
private void receiveMessage(String message, @Header(value = "MessageId") String messageId) {
    S3EventNotification notification = S3EventNotification.parseJson(message);
    //do whatever you need
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Spring Cloud Messaging docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_consuming_aws_event_messages_with_amazon_sqs), you need to configure your own `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` with `strictContentTypeMatch` set to false.

Then your code should work:

```
@MessageMapping("MediaQueue")
private void receiveMessage(S3EventNotificationRecord message, @Headers Map<String, String> headers) {
    System.out.println("MYK MYK MYK");
}
```